# Why is awk printing this line more than once?

Tags: awk, ldif

I have the following ldif:

```
dn: cn=Robert Smith,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Robert Smith
cn: Robert J Smith
cn: bob  smith
sn: smith
uid: rjsmith
userpassword: rJsmitH
carlicense: HISCAR 123
homephone: 555-111-2222
mail: r.smith@example.com
alias: rsmith@example.com
alias: bob.smith@example.com
description: nice hair
ou: Human Resources

dn: cn=John Doe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: John Doe
cn: John Walker Doe
cn: Johnny
sn: Doe
uid: jdoe
userpassword: topsecret
carlicense: AKAHH 123
homephone: 123-458-362
mail: j.doe@example.com
alias: jdoe@example.com
alias: john.doe@example.com
description: cool guy
ou: Sales
```

Now I am running an awk command against it:

```
awk '/^mail:/ { mail = $2 }; {print mail };' ldif
```

The expected result would be:

```
r.smith@example.com
j.doe@example.com
```

The actual result is:

```
r.smith@example.com
r.smith@example.com
r.smith@example.com
r.smith@example.com
r.smith@example.com
r.smith@example.com
r.smith@example.com
r.smith@example.com
r.smith@example.com
r.smith@example.com
r.smith@example.com
r.smith@example.com
r.smith@example.com
r.smith@example.com
r.smith@example.com
r.smith@example.com
j.doe@example.com
j.doe@example.com
j.doe@example.com
j.doe@example.com
j.doe@example.com
```

I don't really understand why awk gives this output multiple times. I'd highly appreciate it if someone could explain it to me since I am new to awk and haven't used it much before. I already consulted the man page and Google, but I guess I am looking for the wrong things there...

EDIT: I understand that awk processes text streams in lines. I guess my "print" simply prints the output as often as there are lines in my ldif file. But how can I prevent awk from doing that? I only want to print each result once..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition `/^mail:/` doesn't affect all instructions that follow, only the first one (`mail = $2`).

As a result, the second instruction (`print mail`) gets executed **for every line**.

That's why there are actually a few blank lines at the start of the output (`mail` isn't set yet).

Any of these will work:

```
awk '/^mail:/ { { mail=$2 }; {print mail } };' ldif

awk '/^mail:/ { mail=$2; print mail };' ldif
```

Personally, I'd prefer:

```
awk '/^mail:/ { print $2 }' ldif
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Can you point me to a link which explains why i need those brackets ( ) and why I need those {} multiple times?

Comment: Sorry, the parentheses were a leftover from trial and error and are actually not needed. I don't have a link right now, but in **any** language a condition only affects the following instruction, unless you group several instructions (by wrapping them, in `awk`'s case, in curly brackets).

Answer (score 1):

@Dennis offered a solution that provides the correct syntax, but didn't fully answer the original question of "Why is awk printing this line more than once?"

Awk runs in a line-oriented loop, and with minor exceptions (e.g. BEGIN and END) runs the entire script on each line of input. In the OP's example, the following pseudo-code was being run for each line of the input file:

```
if LINE starts with "mail:"
    set MAIL to value of second field of the input record
endif

print MAIL
```

The reason for the duplicated lines of output is that the print statement is **outside** the conditional statement, and is therefore executed for *every* line of input, rather than just lines that match the regular expression. Furthermore, since the `mail` variable is only being set inside the conditional statement, the old value is re-used over and over until the next time an input line matches the conditional statement.